# Does Samba 4 come with an internal LDAP server?

Tags: linux, ldap, samba

Does Samba include capability to create an internal LDAP server? I am using Samba version 4.0.3 on Fedora 18, and it is installed from the package manager. How do I go about setting up the internal LDAP server that comes with Samba? What process needs to be started for the internal LDAP server to be running?

I am still coming up to speed on many of the terms used when discussing Samba and LDAP, so a more introductory answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Samba4 FAQ](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/FAQ):

> Will Samba 4 eventually have a built-in, full fledged LDAP server?
>
> Yes. While we certainly won't compare ourselves with the
>   standards-based products from other vendors (our aim is to please AD
>   clients first, and hopefully do so while complying with the
>   standards), it will include an LDAPv3 server.

You will have to set Samba 4 up as an [AD DC](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO) to use the internal LDAP server, but as stated above, it will not be standards compliant. Samba 4 is designed to be an Active Directory server, and will be as LDAP-like as Active Directory normally is.

Answer (score 0):

Samba doesn't provide an LDAP server itself, but can be configured to authenticate against an external LDAP server.

**Edit:** As JohnGardeniers points out, this is incorrect. From the [4.0.0 release notes](http://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.0.0.html):

> Our Domain Controller (DC) implementation includes our own built-in
>   LDAP server and Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) as well as the
>   Samba3-like logon services provided over CIFS.

Comment: The question is specifically about Samba 4, for which your answer is incorrect. In fact there is no support for Samba 4 with an external LDAP server.

Comment: @Dylan I suggest you unaccept this answer and wait for someone to provide more detail.

Comment: This was the main source of my confusion and the main reason for this question. There appears to be conflicting documentation on the internet about whether Samba 4 includes its own LDAP server. Hopefully someone will be able to provide further insight.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the built-in server wasn't there in beta versions. The wiki seems outdated since the samba3 to samba4 upgrade still uses openldap. There are a lot of contradiction in the wiki and few up 2 date informations. Hope the software is not as beta as the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Samba4 for Fedora is not DC ready yet.
See:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Samba4

Had this problem when tried to migrate my Samba4alpha on Fedora17 to Samba4.0 on Fedora18.
As I understand it might be not until 4.1